# separate a string with spaces

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char

How do you separate a word that the user inputs with spaces using a for loop.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  int i;

  System.out.print("Enter a word > ");
  String word = scan.next();

  for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
     System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
  }
```

Comment: You can use `System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " ");`

Comment: What is the error you get? What's not working?

Comment: I wasn't getting an error message, it just kept printing the word with no spaces in between the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: you put a space after printing you printed the word:

```
for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
   System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
}
System.out.print(" ");
```

Alternatively you could print the whole word as one:

```
System.out.print(word + " ");
```

If you want to put a space between each letter:

```
for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
   System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " ");
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew it would be something as simple as that, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " ");
}//end of for loop
```

This code will make a String such as "HelloWorld!" Display as:
"H e l l o W o r l d !"